# Calling method from click binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, coffeescript

I have this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jj258ykp/2/

with BTN2 and BTN3 I see the alert when I click, I don't see an alert on BTN1, I would like to see it.

Here's the coffeescript:

```
class A

    method: -> 
        alert "method"

    method2: -> 
        alert "method2"

    @method3: -> 
        alert "method3"

    setup: -> 
        $('button#btn').click( (event) -> 
          @method()
        )
        $('button#btn3').click( (event) -> 
          A.method3()
        )



$ ->
    a = new A
    a.setup()

    $('button#btn2').click( (event) -> 
          a.method2()
        )
```

and here's my HTML:

```
<button id = "btn">BTN1</button>
<button id = "btn2">BTN2</button>
<button id = "btn3">BTN3</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to reference `this.method()` (the `@` in coffeescript means `this`).

Since the call is within the scope of the click handler, `this.method` wont exist. You need to access it by either instantiating `A` or making `method` a member variable like `method3`:

```
  setup: -> 
    $('button#btn').click( (event) -> 
      new A().method();
    )
```

Or:

```
A
  @method: -> 
    alert "method"

  setup: -> 
    $('button#btn').click( (event) -> 
      A.method();
    )
```

Comment: they could also bind: `$('button#btn').bind 'click', (event) =>`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand what's the difference from BTN2, that contains a reference to `a`

Comment: @dongiulio: the value of `@` (AKA `this`) depends on how a function is called, not (generally) on how it is defined or where it is declared. When jQuery calls a callback, jQuery will set `@` to the relevant DOM element so `@` will be the `#btn` element inside your click handler, not the `A` instance.